# Use google play Services for names of buildings

Tags: android

How can I get the name of the buildings used google play service?

```
   public void getLocation(View v) {

    // If Google Play Services is available
    if (servicesConnected()) {

        // Get the current location
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getProvider(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Display the current location in the UI
        mLatLng.setText(LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, currentLocation));
        mLatLng.setText(LocationUtils.getLatLng(this, currentLocation));
    }
}
public void getNamebuilding(View v) {
    // ??????????????????????????
}
```

**this names!**
http://imageshack.com/a/img850/2897/jxkt.jpg

thanks for the help 
;-)

Answer (score 0):

Android **`google play services Maps api v2`** does **not** providing any support for getting place details by location details.

But you can get location details via **`Google places API`** by making asynchronous http calls. And can get the place details by the location details.

Go through this. This will help you out.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

[Getting a place name in google map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096044/getting-a-place-name-in-google-map-in-android)

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/